# using a known host key with a reverse-tunneled ssh gateway

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I'm using reverse tunneling to provide access to an SSH server via `ProxyJump`, but I'm having trouble getting the client to remember the host public key. Despite indicating it "permanently added  to the list of known hosts", I get the same message *with the same key* when I try to reconnect later. Password authentication is disabled. I've already generated keys and copied the public keys as follows:

```
server.local
  keys:
    server.host[.pub]
    server.user[.pub]
  known_hosts:
    proxy.local ssh-rsa <proxy.host.pub>
  authorized_keys:
    ssh-rsa <client.user1.pub>

proxy.local
  keys:
    proxy.host[.pub]
  known_hosts:
    server.local ssh-rsa <server.host.pub>
    [localhost]:50000 ssh-rsa <server.host.pub>
  authorized_keys:
    ssh-rsa <server.user.pub>
    ssh-rsa <client.user2.pub>

client.local
  keys:
    client.user1[.pub]
    client.user2[.pub]
  known_hosts:
    proxy.local ssh-rsa <proxy.host.pub>
    server.local ssh-rsa <server.host.pub>
    [localhost]:50000 ssh-rsa <server.host.pub>
```

With this configuration, connecting the `client` to the `proxy` works fine, and connecting the `server` to the `proxy` (with reverse tunnel) works fine. But when I connect from the `client` to the `server` via the `proxy`, I get a message:

```
The authenticity of host '[localhost]:50000' (<no hostip for proxy command>)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is <fingerprint of server.pub>.
This key is not known by any other names
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?
```

If I select `yes`, it shows the following message and I am able to successfully connect to `server`:

```
Warning: Permanently added '[localhost]:50000' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
```

Even after this, `known_hosts` on both the `proxy` and `client` remains unchanged. If I disconnect and reconnect quickly, I can reconnect without any further prompts. But if I wait a while (~30 minutes or so), I get *the exact same prompt* with *the exact same fingerprint* (which is the same fingerprint as returned by `ssh-keygen -lf /path/to/server.pub`).

I have questions:

1. Which system is sending the "authenticity" warning? Is it `proxy` or is it my own `client`?
2. Why would reconnecting after one minute not trigger the prompt, but reconnecting after thirty minutes does?
3. Is there a log somewhere, or a monitoring tool of some kind, that can help me verify whether the `Permanently added...` message is actually doing anything, and if so, what files it's touching?
4. Is there some special considering I'm missing for setting up known keys when using ProxyJump, reverse tunneling, or both?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the explanation is found in the post
[SSH host key checking cannot disable when using proxy jump](https://serverfault.com/questions/840011/ssh-host-key-checking-cannot-disable-when-using-proxy-jump)
and especially the
[answer by Jakuje](https://serverfault.com/a/840015/18736),
which I quote here:

> The `ProxyJump` issues another `ssh` process, that does not inherit
> the command-line arguments that you specify on the command-line of the
> first `ssh` command. There are two possible ways out:
>
> - Use these options in configuration file in `~/.ssh/config` -- it
>   can save you a lot of typing too!
>
>   ```
>    Host jumpbox
>      User jumpuser
>      StrictHostKeyChecking=no
>      UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
>      IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_jumpuser_rsa
>   ```
>
> and then you can connect just as `ssh -J jumpbox jumpuser@10.10.0.5`.
>
> - Use `ProxyCommand` option instead -- it does the same job, but more
>   transparently so you can see what is actually going on there:
>
> `ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -i ~/.ssh/id_jumpuser_rsa -W %h:%p jumpuser@jumpbox" -i ~/.ssh/id_jumpuser_rsa jumpuser@10.10.0.5`

The explanation of the second SSH process accounts for why your
local known keys don't work, as they are just not passed on.
I would guess that the second SSH stays on for about 30 minutes,
to handle future connections, then terminates itself after 30 minutes
of inactivity.